# Node js and HTML:

Tags: node.js

Here is what I have: a html with a form that contains nothing but radio buttons, when i go to the local site the html page shows. which is what i wanted, now i need figure out how to : when the submit button in the html page is selected the data will be saved and a second html page (containing the statistics from the form ) will display. so what i am only trying  understand is how to get a second simple html page to show so i can make sure i am doing it correctly. the second page is hello world.  my question is when the submit button is pressed, how do i redirect to a second page using nodejs. 
what my html is doing for form

```
<form method='POST'action=\secondpage.html'>
```

what my node is doing:

```
function onRequest(request,response){
  console.log("its working " );

    if(request.method =='GET' && request.url == "/"){
         console.log('found form page');
         response.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type":"text/html"});
         fs.createReadStream("./assignemnt3.html").pipe(response);
    }

    if(request.method =='POST' && request.url == "/secondpage.html"){
           return response.redirect("./secondpage.html");
     }

  }
```

Comment: Can you please explain why you are using   fs.createReadStream ?

Comment: i was following a tutorial i found.  is there another way?

Comment: I think you don't have close your brackets properly

Comment: That was one issue

Comment: Can you please add your route function ?

Comment: i currently do not have a route function.

Comment: Can you please share the link from where you was following a tutorial ?

Answer (score 0):

You placed the 'POST' condition inside the 'GET' condition; as a result, it will never get called.

```
function onRequest(request,response){
    console.log("its working " );

    if(request.method =='GET' && request.url == "/"){
        console.log('found form page');
        response.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type":"text/html"});
        fs.createReadStream("./assignemnt3.html").pipe(response);
    }

    if (request.method =='POST') {
        console.log('It is a POST');
        return response.redirect("./secondpage.html");
    }

}
```

Comment: when i comment out the POST if statement my form page shows,  when i uncomment , the page displays as error pages not found. Does the request need to go to a different funciton?

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, my form action was point at the wrong location. if i point it at the URL it sends the form back to the node with the post data.